# Pagination result with Spring data JPA stored procedure

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

How I can retrieve pagination result when trying to call spring data JPA stored procedure.

Comment: Wich point is not clear? Classicly you should annotate your repository method with @Procedure(name = "procedure_name") and then pass your pagination params in this method and expect a Page as return type.

Comment: I'm looking for out of the box support in spring data JPA to retrieve pagination result.

Comment: You're right! Being lazy is a good thing in programming (but not too much) :D

Comment: work smart is better than work hard without any reason, out of the box support it gives you chance to focus on your business rule.

Answer (score 3):

There is no explicit support for this. 
Therefore all you can really do is create a wrapper method, that takes pageable, uses it to pass the required parameters to the stored procedure, takes the result and wraps it in a page object.

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve List and then convert to Pageable

```
return new PageImpl<>(storedProcedureQuery.getResultList(), PageRequest.of(page, size));
```